# About Magento Currency Setting,The price is multiplied by two exchange rates。

Tags: magento2

I set in accordance with the official documents my mall exchange rate.
[image]

But at the front end, the price is really not accurate。I have a product price of 10 dollars。Follow the exchange rate,TI should be around £ 8 ,Obviously, it is multiplied by two exchange rates here！[image]

[image]

I do not know where my configuration error, I have clearly cached and refresh the index。Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you resolved this issue?

Comment: I have temporarily solved this problem，I found the same problem on github and got it solved。https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10490

Answer (score 0):

I think You have missing import currency rates.

Please import currency rates & save it from `Store >> Currency >> Currency Rates >> Import >> Save Currency Rates`